# Phonegap paypal plugin

Tags: android, cordova, paypal

I have to implement 2 payment gateways: one for India and another for other countries
While using paypal plugin i get the following error.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.PayPal.invoke')

Though the same plugin works fine for india's payment gateway, but for other countries it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the jar file you imported. There are two jar files in developers site , import the right one to solve the error..